# AVerMedia A309-B mini-PCI to AVerMedia A317 Mini PCI card

Tags: laptop, pci-express, tuner-card, minipci

I got an HP pavilion hdx 16 1060ED laptop (Windows Vista)
with a a DVB-T tuner card

Now I would like a hybrid or analog turner card in it.

According to the HP data of a more expensive variant, a AVerMedia A317 Mini PCI card installed is installed.

My system has a AVerMedia A309-B mini-PCI placed in the system.

my questions:

1. Is it possible to replace it with a expensive one (AVerMedia A317 Mini PCI card)?
2. I can build it myself and what can I do with the old card?

I like to hear from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is possible to replace. However, are you sure you have a Mini-PCI and not a mini-PCIe?

   [image]

   From what I can tell, you have a mini-PCIe. newer laptops have them, and the card you listed as currently in your system appears to be mini-PCIe. So I would say yes.
2. About [50$](http://cgi.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=370390213064&rvr_id=&crlp=1_263602_263622&UA=%3F*F%3F&GUID=fdf354221280a0aad236ba46fe46e45a&itemid=370390213064&ff4=263602_263622).
3. You can probably do it yourself. You just open your computer, pull the old card out, put the new card in, and turn your computer back on. Vista should install the drivers automatically. if it doesn't, finding them isn't to hard. as for the old card, probably just trash it. maybe see if some one on eBay wants it.